# How to create a fake/dummy Windows tree from other Windows tree with Windows shell?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, directory-structure

I have a big Windows directory and file tree. Now I need to copy this tree to another location but I do not want to copy the contents from each file. Only the structure and filenames with 0 bytes contents are needed. How could this be done with as cmd shell in Windows 10?

What I did:

1. `xcopy /t e:\oldtreedir  e:\new\oldtreedir`
2. `dir /a /b /s > mybat.bat`
3. edit mybat.bat to:

   ```
   replace \ne:\ to 
   \ncopy nul e:\new\
   ```

   so that it is for each filename the line

   ```
   copy nul e:\new\oldtreedir\file1.txt
   ```

I had to edit the mybat.bat. Could this be done by a script in the Windows command line?

PS: I found this: [WIN-PRg](https://hangvogel.hypermart.net/txt2fil/) but this program do not create a dir-tree. All files are in one dir only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got your question right, [`robocopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) should do the trick:

```cmd
robocopy "E:\oldtreedir" "E:\new\oldtreedir" "*.*" /E /CREATE
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to create an additonal batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

xcopy /t e:\oldtreedir  e:\new\oldtreedir

for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d "e:\oldtreedir\*"') do (
  set "file=%%a"
  set "file=!file:E:\=E:\new\!"
  break>"!file!"
)
```

Comment: You should also consider @aschipfl's answer. It's more reliable and probably faster.